# Cisco erase nvram or erase startup-config doesn't work

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios

According to this article, I can delete the current startup configuration files and return the router to its factory default settings with the `erase nvram:` and `reload` command.

https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/cisco-ios-cookbook/0596527225/ch01s06.html

```
R1#erase ?
  /all                       Erase all files(in NVRAM)
  /no-squeeze-reserve-space  Do not reserve space for squeeze operation
  flash:                     Filesystem to be erased
  nvram:                     Filesystem to be erased
  pram:                      Filesystem to be erased
  slot0:                     Filesystem to be erased
  startup-config             Erase contents of configuration memory

R1#erase nvram: ?
  <cr>

R1#erase nvram: 
Erasing the nvram filesystem will remove all configuration files! Continue? [confirm]
[OK]
Erase of nvram: complete
R1#
*Mar  1 00:07:24.891: %SYS-7-NV_BLOCK_INIT: Initialized the geometry of nvram
R1#
```

I also tried `erase startup-config` and `reload`

The problem is nothing happens after that. It just stop responding right after `reload` command entered.

```
R1#reload 
Proceed with reload? [confirm]
```

I did not get any prompt to proceed with reload as shown in the [link](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/cisco-ios-cookbook/0596527225/ch01s06.html) above (or just refer to example below).

```
Router1#reload

System configuration has been modified. Save? [yes/no]: no
Proceed with reload? [confirm]<enter>
```

Comment: What do you mean “nothing happens “?

Comment: @RonTrunk, I've updated my question. It just stop responding right after `reload` command entered.

Comment: Are you connected to the serial console port at the default settings? (9600 8n1) It does take a minute for the system to POST.

Comment: @RickyBeam, yes .. console, not physical bu virtual as this running on GNS3